# How to check if an option is selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, selected

i'm trying to check if an option i've chosen is selected.

```
<select id="fontStyle" name="fontStyle">
    <option value="alpha-echo" selected >Alpha Echo</option>
    <option value="anagram">Anagram</option>
</select>
```

I've used `if( $("#fontStyle option").val('anagram'))` but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: `if( $("#fontStyle option").val() === 'anagram' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get the value of selected option from `select` list:

```
$( "#fontStyle option:selected" ).val();
```

This will give you the `alpha-echo` for your provided html. And if you want to check if the `anagram` is selected, you will need to do:

```
if($( "#fontStyle option:selected" ).val()=='anagram'){}
```

Comment: If i need to get the value of the other option how will it happen?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'value of other option'? Are you trying to set the `anagram` as selected option?